# How to remove Frame.BackStackDepth?

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I am developing a **windows 8.1** app which includes **several pages**. I want to know how can I remove **Frame.BackStackDepth** so that when user press the **back button** the app will navigate to the **first page.**

I tried this but it remove the previous Frame only.

```
private void backButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Frame.BackStack.RemoveAt(this.Frame.BackStackDepth-1);
    this.Frame.GoBack();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this extension method:

```
public static void ResetBackStack(this Frame frame)
{
    PageStackEntry mainPage = frame.BackStack.Where(b => b.SourcePageType == typeof(YourPageType)).FirstOrDefault();
    frame.BackStack.Clear();
    if (mainPage != null)
    {
        frame.BackStack.Add(mainPage);
    }
}
```

Just override the BackPressed event inside your NavigationHelper class: call that extension method with your frame and then navigate back.

Or just put it inside your EventHandler:

```
private void backButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Frame.ResetBackStack();
    this.Frame.GoBack();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know from the Windows Phone, you cannot remove backstack with a command or method. it is not such easy. You have to use loops till `CanGoBack` returns false. This is only way to do this.

I imagined your logic so, remove all pages in backstack except the first opened page. The loop continues up to exception.

Do not forget to define your first page name instead `FirstPage`.

Also please check the msdn link for more information.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/3819f389-3bfc-4c59-a919-272927fc9229/navigation-in-a-metro-application?forum=winappswithcsharp

Try this solution.

```
do
{
    this.Frame.BackStack.RemoveAt(this.Frame.BackStackDepth - 1);
} while (Frame.CanGoBack && Frame.BackStack.Last(entry => entry.SourcePageType != typeof(FirstPage)) != null);

this.Frame.GoBack();
```